# How do I get tds refund when the processed ITR mentions 0 as tds refund? (India)

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, income-tax-refund

While filing itr the auto populated information showed that I am eligible for a refund but after the itr has been processed by the officer there is no indication of tax refund in the processed ITR.

[pre processed form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAtYX.jpg)
[post assessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP65n.jpg)

Comment: It looks like the IT department is saying that the TDS you are claiming (~51k) has not been received by them.  Do you have this value in your Form 16

Comment: Yes the form 16 from my employer mentions total deduction under sec 16 mentions the same amount on the right column

Comment: Check on this goverment site to verify the TDS   https://www.tdscpc.gov.in/app/tapn/tdstcscredit.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for pointing at the right direction. I just checked tds 26as and there's no transaction. Should I take this issue to my  employer?

Comment: Talk to your employer.  There seems to be some mistake somewhere.  For the amount of income you have, there should be no TDS.  50k is way too much

Comment: I did contact my employer, they are saying no tds was deducted. That 50k amount is the amount refundable as standard.